# Test for GHC compile time errors

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack, hpack

I'm working on [proto-lens#400](https://github.com/google/proto-lens/pull/400) tweaking a Haskell code generator. In one of the tests I'd like to verify that certain API has *not* been built. Specifically, I want to ensure that a certain type of program will not type check successfully. I'd also have a similar program with one identifier changed which *should* compile, to guard against a typo breaking the test. Reading [Extending and using GHC as a Library](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/extending_ghc.html) I have managed to have my test write a small file and compile it using GHC as a library.

But I need the code emitted by the test to load some other modules. Specifically the output of the code generator of that project and its runtime environment with transitive dependencies. I have at best a very rough understanding of stack and hpack, which is providing the build time system. I know I can add dependencies to [some `package.yaml` file](https://github.com/google/proto-lens/blob/6bc43468cc3e61a8d41e6a4cf96cc1ea0698d803/proto-lens-tests/package.yaml) to make them available to individual tests, but I have no clue how to access such dependencies from the GHC session set up as part of running the test. I imagine I might find some usable data in some environment variables, but I also believe such an approach might be undocumented and prone to break without warning.

How can I have a test case use GHC as a library and have it access dependencies expressed in `package.yaml`? Or alternatively, can I use some construct other than a regular test case to express a file with dependencies but check that the file won't compile?

Comment: Maybe this package could be useful for you? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/should-not-typecheck

Comment: Alternatively, the `type-spec` package might be useful here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-spec-0.4.0.0/docs/Test-TypeSpec-ShouldBe.html#t:ShouldNotBe

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this applies to you because there are too many details going way over my head, but one way to test for type errors is to build your test suite with `-fdefer-type-errors` and to catch the exception at run-time (of type [`TypeError`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#t:TypeError)).